# Expand defines with GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

How can I expand or collapse the defines in the header file for example

```
#define IOC_IN 0x80000000
#define IOC_WS2 0x08000000
#define _WSAIOW(x,y)(IOC_IN|(x)|(y))
#define SIO_ASSOCIATE_HANDLE _WSAIOW(IOC_WS2,1)
```

I tried doing `gcc -E file.h > output.h` however this outputs an empty file. I am using MingW compiler.

I expect the defines to be subsituted like this:

```
#define IOC_IN 0x80000000
#define IOC_WS2 0x08000000
#define _WSAIOW(x,y)(IOC_IN|(x)|(y))
#define SIO_ASSOCIATE_HANDLE (IOC_IN|(IOC_WS2)|(1))
```

Comment: update the question with the expected output.

Comment: *sigh*. real output. I'm asking this because your textual description is vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC (the preprocessor actually) ignores your defines because they are unused. Try appending `int x = SIO_ASSOCIATE_HANDLE;` and rerun the gcc.

Answer (score 2):

The defines "in the header" are not "expanded", what do you expect to happen?

Instead, places where they are *used* are going to be preprocessed to have the definitions inserted.

You typically preprocess a C file, not a header, i.e. something where a `#define` is used without being defined.